# Array push.apply with getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, getelementsbyclassname

I have this array a where I wanna be able to add numbers and text, from a input and by simply typing the text or number into a input and then run a function.
This is what I have so fare. My Problem is, that every time i type something into my form and run the function, it says it's empty.

```
<button onclick="mere()">Tryk</button>

<form name="holder">

<input type="text" class="challenge" name="challenge[]" size="10"><br/>

</form>

var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

function mere() {
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName( 'challenge' ),
names  = [].map.call(inputs, function( input ) {
    return input.value;
}).join( '|' );


if (inputs > 0){
a.push.apply(a, inputs);
console.log(inputs);
}
else {
alert("empty")
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you, but it adds input.challenge to the array, I really want it to add the number, lets say 3, i enter in the input

Comment: You might want to use `names` since that contains the values`.

Comment: Still doesn't work, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The test should be

```
if(inputs.length > 0) {
...
```